# Why does networkx not read my csv dataset file opened with pd.read_csv using nx.read function?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, edge-list

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/leokarl/Downloads/a2 (1).csv")

import networkx as nx

G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(df)
```

It prints the error:

`Edge data ['ID1;ID2;%', 'in', 'ID2;number', 'identical', 'lines'] and data_keys (('weight', <class 'float'>),) are not the same length`

If I use
`G = nx.read_edgelist(df)` it prints out the error:

`Failed to convert edge data (['ID1;ID2;%', 'in', 'ID2;number', 'identical', 'lines']) to dictionary`

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear to you about why nx.read fails. You are giving it one list containing 5 strings and one tuple containing another tuple of two objects. How did you expect this to work?

Comment: @mkrieger1 What can I do that it will work?

Comment: I don't know. Pass data to the `nx.read_*` functions in a form that they understand, instead of the data you are passing now.

Comment: @mkrieger1  Your explanation is not helping me.

Comment: It looks like you should be using `sep=";"` in your `.read_csv` along with [`nx.from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html#networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist)